# How to determinate a toric section?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-curves

I just found an a class of curves named ***toric section***.
Essentially like conic sections but instead of a cone intersected by a plane, it is a torus.

They have this equation (except for rototranslations)
$$\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}+ax^{2}+by^{2}+cx+dy+e=0$$
Some toric sections are:

1. Bernoulli lemniscate
2. Booth lemniscate
3. Cardioid
4. Anellus
5. Cassini ovals
6. Limacon
7. Ippoid

Is there a list of all toric section and how to determinate in by the equation?
Like for conic section, associating a matrix of coefficients.
Maybe it can be usefull considering this matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&a&0&c\\0&0&b&d\\0&c&d&e\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Are the torii you consider with a $R>r$ or do you accept spindle torii with $R \le r$ ?

Comment: It is always good to cite sources. Apparently [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00803.pdf) document looks to be one of your sources. Am I right ? Besides, I don't think this subfamily of bicircular quartics can be treated by associating it a matrix, like we do for conic curves.

Comment: See an answer of mine (a long time ago) : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2470345/305862

Comment: Any comment ?...